# Which functors agree only on objects?

Tags: category-theory

Is there a term to describe when two functors agree on objects but generally differ on morphisms? I would appreciate any elaboration about what this structure implies.

Thanks!

Comment: There's rather a lot of such: for example, all non-identity group homomorphisms, with the groups viewed as categories.

Comment: Essentially this would be two different representations of the category on the same objects. This would be specialize for example to two different representations of the same group on the same vector space, and there's not really a word for this concept. In general, the objects in a category are much less important than the morphisms. Also speaking of objects up to equality rather than isomorphism is not very useful in category theory most of the time.

Comment: @user3482749  Thanks very much.

Comment: @jgon  Thanks very much for these very helpful pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ the category with 1 object and 2 non-identity morphism $a$ and $b$ such that $a\circ b=b\circ a =id$ (a non-trivial isomorphism). Then we have two functors $F,G:C\to C$ that necessarily agree on objects, but differ on the morphisms. Namely, take $F$ to be the identity functor (the non-identity morphisms go to themselves), and $G$ takes each non-identity morphisms to the other.

This works for instance for any group with a non trivial isomorphism. In fact, as have been said in the comments, all non-identity group homomorphisms yield a functor with the characteristics that you are looking for.